# ArgumentNullException when calling a RoutedEvent

Tags: wpf, vb.net, routed-events

The following code produces an ArgumentNullException:

```
Public Custom Event PlayerDetailRequested As RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler(Of Player)

    AddHandler(ByVal value As RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler(Of Player))
        Me.AddHandler(PlayerDetailRequestedEvent, value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler(Of Player))
        Me.RemoveHandler(PlayerDetailRequestedEvent, value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Player))
        Me.RaiseEvent(e)
    End RaiseEvent
End Event

Public Shared ReadOnly PlayerDetailRequestedEvent As RoutedEvent = _
                  EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("PlayerDetailRequested", _
                  RoutingStrategy.Bubble, _
                  GetType(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler(Of Player)), GetType(PlayersManagementControl))



  Private Sub Hyperlink_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent PlayerDetailRequested(Me, New RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Player)(SelectedPlayer, SelectedPlayer))
    End Sub
```

The Exception is thrown on the call to `Me.RaiseEvent(e)`

It is very hard to find working examples in VB and C sharp's event handling is different. Please help me keep my sanity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is explained in the `Exception`: `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: routedEvent`. `RoutedEvent` is a property of a `RoutedEventArgs`. You have to provide the `RoutedEvent` instance you are raising, in your case it is `PlayerDetailRequestedEvent`. Try this piece of code:

```
    Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
            Me.RaiseEvent(New RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Player)(SelectedPlayer, SelectedPlayer, PlayerDetailRequestedEvent))
    End Sub
```